# Index not being used for sort in joined view

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `news_category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `news_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `news_pictures_main_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `body` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `tmstp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `subcategory` varchar(64) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `news_time_idx` (`tmstp`),
  KEY `fk_news_news_pictures1` (`news_pictures_main_id`),
  KEY `fk_news_news_category1` (`news_category_id`),
  KEY `fk_news_news_type1` (`news_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_news_news_category1` FOREIGN KEY (`news_category_id`) REFERENCES `news_category` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_news_news_pictures1` FOREIGN KEY (`news_pictures_main_id`) REFERENCES `news_pictures` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_news_news_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`news_type_id`) REFERENCES `news_type` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `news_pictures` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `path` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `description` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `author` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `news_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_id` varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `filename_old_id_unq` (`path`(20),`temp_id`(6)),
  KEY `fk_news_pictures_news1` (`news_id`),
  KEY `temp_id_idx` (`temp_id`(8)),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_news_pictures_news1` FOREIGN KEY (`news_id`) REFERENCES `news` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `news_category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `news_type` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  KEY `news_type_slug_idx` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

From that, there is derived the following view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `news_full` AS select `n`.`id` AS `id`,
`n`.`title` AS `title`,
`n`.`body` AS `body`,
`n`.`tmstp` AS `tmstp`,
`n`.`subcategory` AS `subcategory`,
`n`.`source` AS `source`,
`n`.`old_id` AS `old_id`,
`n`.`news_type_id` AS `news_type_id`,
`n`.`tags` AS `tags`,
`nt`.`name` AS `news_type_name`,
`nt`.`slug` AS `news_type_slug`,
`n`.`news_pictures_main_id` AS `news_pictures_main_id`,
`np`.`path` AS `news_pictures_main_path`,
`np`.`description` AS `news_pictures_main_description`,
`np`.`author` AS `news_pictures_main_author`,
`np`.`temp_id` AS `news_pictures_main_temp_id`,
`n`.`news_category_id` AS `news_category_id`,
`nc`.`name` AS `news_category_name` 
from (((`news` `n` 
            left join `news_pictures` `np` on((`n`.`news_pictures_main_id` = `np`.`id`))) 
        join `news_category` `nc` on((`n`.`news_category_id` = `nc`.`id`))) 
    join `news_type` `nt` on((`n`.`news_type_id` = `nt`.`id`)));
```

However, if I try to run the following query:

```
select * from news_full order by tmstp limit 100
```

I get the following execution plan (please click on the image to expand it):

[image: Explain result]

Notice the `Using temporary; Using filesort` field in the first step. But this is weird, because `tmstp` field is indexed on the base table.

First I thought this was due the `left join` on the view, but I've changed it to `inner join` and I got the same results.

---

**Edit**

As @Michael-sqlbot cleverly noticed, the query optimizer is inverting the order of the base tables, putting `news_category` (`nc`) first.

If I change the query that creates the view to use only `LEFT JOIN`s it seems to work:

[image: New query plan]

The execution times, as expected, as blatantly different:
[image: Query comparison]

Not satisfied, I created another view with the original query, adding the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` statement. So, the query plan comes as follows:

[image: Query plan - straight join]

So, it's not using the index.

However, if I run the plan for the base query adding the same `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses, it **does** uses the index:

[image: Query plan - straight join no view]

Comment: MySQL cannot use an index in a view. So there's not much point in views in MySQL.

Comment: I've heard that you cannot CREATE indexes in views in MySQL, but it does uses indexes from the underlying tables to run queries. I don't have any references, though. If you have one that proves me wrong, could you please post it here?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html

Comment: I'll have to call you on that @Strawberry (first time for everything).  As long as the view can use the `MERGE` algorithm, indexes are used as expected because the statement invoking the view is merged with the view definition and the resulting query is processed optimally: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-algorithms.html ... the question, here, is this: what plan does the original query (the view definition) generate if run directly, with the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`?

Comment: Follow-up question: what happens to the query plan if all three joins are left joins?  Note that in the query plan shown, the first table is actually `nc` -- the optimizer has reordered the tables, which is quite valid logically with an inner join but not an outer join... but in this case the optimizer is overthinking itself into a corner.   Or, using the original query, see what you get when you add `STRAIGHT_JOIN` to the beginning, e.g. `select STRAIGHT_JOIN \`n\`.\`id\` AS \`id\`, ...`

Comment: @michael good call. Yep, but I don't see how merge relates here. Happy to be shown otherwise.

Comment: @Strawberry this query plan indicates the server is using `MERGE` to integrate the outer query into the view definition (not rendering the whole view then applying `ORDER` and `LIMIT`).  [If it weren't, it would show a `DERIVED` table](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54491/11651).  The actual problem here, I believe, is that *this query won't use that index for sorting even if not used inside the view*, because the optimizer is reordering the tables. To `ORDER BY` from an index, the table with the index has to be first in the plan so that the server can initially read those rows in index order.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot your suggestion seems to work, I'll edit the question with further details.

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer, but some other issues to bring up...)

```
UNIQUE KEY `filename_old_id_unq` (`path`(20),`temp_id`(6))
```

- That constrains the first 20 characters of `path`, together with the first 6 characters of `temp_id` to be unique across the table.  Did you really want that?
- I suspect the optimizer will *never* use both columns of that index.  (In general, prefixing is useless.)

And...

```
`title` tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci
```

Change to `VARCHAR(255)`.  There are disadvantages of `TINYTEXT` and perhaps no advantages.

Comment: About the index, that's because `path` and `temp_id` are 20 and 6 chars wide respectively. Why the optimizer will never use both columns? I have a query that has a `WHERE` clause like `WHERE path = $1 and temp_id = $2`.

Comment: If they are always 20 and 6 characters, then declare the columns to be `CHAR(20)` and `CHAR(6)`, then remove the "prefix" from the index.  _Then_ the optimizer will get past the truncated first column.